# Odd Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'll get right to it.
So I have code that gets a Null Pointer Exception. I've tried looking up what causes it and how to fix it, but that's why I'm confused with this particular code. It was working just fine earlier today and now its throwing the exception. Any help? I'm probably just overlooking something silly but it's quite frustrating. Code follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ShopMain<T> {
List<T> stock;


public void Shop() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); }

public T buy() { return stock.remove(0); }

void sell(T item) { stock.add(item); }

void buy(int n, Collection<? super T>items) {
    for (T e : stock.subList(0, n)) {
    items.add(e);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) stock.remove(0);
}

void sell(Collection<? extends T>  items) {
    for (T e : items) {
    stock.add(e);
    }
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
ShopMain<Marker> paintballShop = new ShopMain<Marker>();
Console console = System.console();
System.out.println("1 - Test Suite");
String input = console.readLine("Please select the corresponding number to your choice.\n");
if(input.equals("1")){
    Stack<Marker> stack = new Stack<Marker>();
    Set<Marker> hashset = new HashSet<Marker>();
    System.out.println("Test Suite : Tests List, Stack, HashSet");
    paintballShop.sell(new Geo3()); 
    paintballShop.sell(new Ego11());
    paintballShop.buy();
    paintballShop.buy(2, stack); //Stack use
    paintballShop.sell(stack); //Stack use
    paintballShop.buy(3, hashset); //HashSet
    paintballShop.sell(hashset); //HashSet
    System.out.println("Tests Complete");

}
}
}
```

Exception error occurring at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ShopMain.sell(ShopMain.java:14)
    at ShopMain.main(ShopMain.java:39)
```

These last bits are just class 'placeholders' for the objects and their parent class.

```
public class Marker{}

public class Geo3 extends Marker{}

public class Ego11 extends Marker{}
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: 'Shop()' why this function there, you mean constructor?

Answer (score 2):

That's because your List `List<T> stock;` is still uninitialized. You need to initialize it for you to be able to add, remove elements to/from it. By default, its `null` and thus, when you try to call a method on it, you get the `NullPointerException`.

This happens because you don't have a constructor at all. `Shop()` is not the constructor of your class. A constructor has the same name as the class, and thus you need to have your constructor like this

```
public ShopMain() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); }
```

---

Incase, `Shop()` is a valid method, then you need to call this method so that your list is initialized and only then call the other methods.

```
paintballShop.Shop(); // Call this method to init your list.
```

Comment: Ahh, yes. I see now, I feel silly. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

change to constructor..

```
public ShopMain() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change:

```
public void Shop() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); } 
//doesn't look a method name, may be this is what you missed
```

to

```
public ShopMain() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a constructor for `ShopMain` that initializes your `List`.

Add this:

```
ShopMain() {
  stock<T> = new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it comes do to the fact that `stock` is never initialised.  I imagine that the class use to be called `Shop`

You could change...

```
public class ShopMain<T> {

    List<T> stock;

    public void Shop() {
        stock = new LinkedList<T>();
    }
```

To...

```
public class ShopMain<T> {

    List<T> stock;

    public ShopMain() {
        stock = new LinkedList<T>();
    }
```

Which will initialise the `List` when the class is constructored...